# PHP fresh installation with fpm & mysqli

Tags: software-installation, 18.10, php7, php-fpm

Studying multiple documentations I've got confused about PHP 7.* installation process.
Do I have to compile it from source with fpm and mysqli options, or may I use package manager like aptitude for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most common things, you won't need to compile. But, depeding on the version of ubuntu that you have and/or the version of php that you want, you may have to install `ondrej/php` ppa.

Comment: Yep, I hoped so... So, fpm and mysqli may be installed from, what, his ppa, or ubuntu repos? I thought that these are only add-ons on php "core"..

Comment: Can you provide your ubuntu version and the version & mode of php (fpm/apache_mod) that you want to install?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 18.10, PHP-fpm 7.3.7 is preferred (with mysqli support). For now I'm fine with 7.2 versions of fpm and mysql packets, but would like to know just for an academic interest..  Also, seems that php-fpm packet installs php core through dependencies (should have known, but my knowledge about Linux is little)..

Comment: I didn't found anything on 18.10, but [this tutorial is for 18.04 & php7.3](https://kifarunix.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-3-on-ubuntu-18-04/). If you don't want to go into linux-specific and try different php versions, you can check out [`php-apache` on docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), really easy to use and it won't mess up your linux installation, and/or can run on osx & windows.